# C++ Builder > __property with Setter(String) causes error [E2034 Cannot convert 'UnicodeString' to 'float']

Tags: c++builder

My environment

```
C++ Builder XE4 on Windows7 Pro (32bit)
```

I tried to make a float-valued property as:

- __property of float value
- setter having [String] argument, where the string is "1e-7" for example
- getter returning in scientific E-notation (e.g. 1e-7)

Unit2.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit2H
#define Unit2H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.hpp>


class TMyClass {
private:
    float FRealValue;
    String GetRealValue();
    void SetRealValue(String strValue);

public:
    __property float RealValue = { read = GetRealValue, write = SetRealValue };

    TMyClass() : RealValue(0.0) {};
};

#endif
```

Unit2.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)


String TMyClass::GetRealValue()
{
    return String().sprintf(L"%e", FRealValue);
}

void TMyClass::SetRealValue(String strValue)
{
    FRealValue = strValue.ToDouble();
}
```

Unit1.h

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // 
    TEdit *E_val1;
    TButton *Button1;
    TEdit *E_val2;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // 
public:     // 
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
```

Unit1.cpp

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include "Unit2.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    E_val1->Text = L"1e-7";
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TMyClass *myInst = new TMyClass();

    myInst->RealValue = E_val1->Text; // (1)

    E_val2->Text = myInst->RealValue;

    delete myInst;

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In the (1) of Unit1.cpp, I have the error:

> Unit1.cpp(23): E2034 Cannot convert 'UnicodeString' to 'float'

Question:
Isn't it possible to take String argument for float value property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a property getter/setter use a different data type than what the property requires.

A getter for a `float` property must return a `float` as output:

```
float __fastcall TMyClass::GetRealValue()
```

A setter for a `float` property must take a `float` as input:

```
void __fastcall TMyClass::SetRealValue(float aValue)
```

The type cannot be a `String` or `int` or any other data type. It must be a `float`.

That is because a property of a certain type is, in fact, translated as calls to its getter and setter functions. So

```
float value = myClass->RealValue;
```

is compiled as:

```
float value = myClass->GetRealValue();
```

and

```
myClass->RealValue = 1.345;
```

is compiled as:

```
myClass->SetRealValue(1.345);
```

**If you want to do what you are trying (strings in and out), you must declare the property as `System::String` instead of `float`.**

Comment: This is technically true, though it can be a little misleading for C++Builders users. The C++ `System::String` class has a constructor that accepts a `double` as input, so `myClass->SetRealValue(1.345)` is valid when `SetRealValue()` expects a `String`. The C++ compiler *could* look at the actual setter signature and allow any valid input regardless of the property type, so `myInst->RealValue = E_val1->Text` (compiled as `myInst->SetRealValue(E_val1->Text)`) *could* be valid when `SetRealValue()` takes a `String`. But the compiler rightly honors the property type and rejects the `String` input

Comment: Fact is that a getter or setter that has a `String` argument can't be used as a getter or setter for a property of type `float`. If the asker wants to use strings to get or set the property, he can simply declare the property as `String`. How this is stored or handled internally doesn't matter.